# Server Error TypeError: _nextProps.children is not a function _document getInitialProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

This is my first question on this forum as I'm new to coding, so please don't be too judgmental.

I'm trying to make my NextJS SSR app responsive. After making some changes to the index.js and some other files I'm getting the following error on the server:

```
TypeError: _nextProps.children is not a function
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (/c/Users/User/Documents/webDev/next-wp-api/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3972:55)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (/c/Users/User/Documents/webDev/next-wp-api/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3690:29)
    at renderToString (/c/Users/User/Documents/webDev/next-wp-api/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:4298:27)
    at renderPage (/c/Users/User/Documents/webDev/next-wp-api/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:50:851)
    at Object.ctx.renderPage (/c/Users/User/Documents/webDev/next-wp-api/.next/server/pages/_document.js:942:26)
    at Function.getInitialProps (/c/Users/User/Documents/webDev/next-wp-api/.next/server/pages/_document.js:299:19)
    at Function.module.exports../pages/_document.js.MyDocument.getInitialProps (/c/Users/User/Documents/webDev/next-wp-api/.next/server/pages/_document.js:950:83)
    at loadGetInitialProps (/c/Users/User/Documents/webDev/next-wp-api/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/lib/utils.js:5:101)
    at renderToHTML (/c/Users/User/Documents/webDev/next-wp-api/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:50:1142)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

The error gets triggered when executing the getInitialProps function inside _document.js (code attached) on the server.

*_document.js*

```js
import React from "react";
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import { ServerStyleSheets } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import theme from "../src/theme";
import { mediaStyle } from "../src/components/utils/Media";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          {/* PWA primary color */}
          <meta name="theme-color" content={theme.palette.primary.main} />
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
          />
          <style
            type="text/css"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: mediaStyle }}
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  
  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
    });

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

  return {
    ...initialProps,
    // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
    styles: [
      ...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles),
      sheets.getStyleElement(),
    ],
  };
};
```

*index.js*

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import wc_api from "../src/api/wooCommerce";
import Header from "../src/components/layout/Header";
import { navData, footerData } from "../src/data";
import { Media } from "../src/components/utils/Media";
import Layout from "../src/components/Layout";
import DefaultApp from "../src/composites/DefaultApp";
import MobileApp from "../src/composites/MobileApp";

export default function Home({ productsData }) {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setProducts(productsData);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-100">
      <Header />
      <Layout>
        <Media at="sm">
          <MobileApp />
        </Media>
        <Media greaterThan="sm">
          <DefaultApp
            navData={navData}
            footerData={footerData}
            products={productsData}
          />
        </Media>
      </Layout>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  let productsData = [];

  try {
    productsData = await wc_api
      .get("products")
      .then((response) => {
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response.data);
      });
    return {
      props: {
        productsData,
      },
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return {
      props: {
        err: "Something went wrong",
      },
    };
  }
}
```

However, I have not done any changes to the _document.js file itself since the last commit. I can't find out by myself what's causing the problem. Please help!

Comment: What other files did you change? Could you try and pinpoint which change exactly triggers the error?

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I figured out what was wrong with my app. I've commented out a context provider (which provided the window size) in a higher order component while not also removing a context consumer in a lower order component. Removing the context consumer fixed it. Thanks for your intention to help anyways!

Comment: i'm also having this problem how did you fix it?

Answer (score 4):

I got this error when importing a module in the wrong way:

```
import MyContextProvider from '../store/my-context';
```

^^ MyContextProvider  is not a default export, so it should be:

```
import { MyContextProvider } from '../store/my-context';
```

Comment: You're my hero today :)